# Java deployment to a cloud for fast computation

Tags: java, cloud, cluster-computing, computation

I have an application written in Java that performs some straightforward but time consuming calculations analysing some texts, printing results to the terminal. I want to speed up the process by deploying that application on a cloud and letting it be calculated there. Which cloud service allows for such deployment with minimal change of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most cloud computing servers are designed to host web applications (Servlets mostly).  I'm guessing your application is not a web application.  You could write a simple web application that wraps around your application and uses some kind of messaging layer to distribute the load.  You could then deploy on any of the major cloud sites (e.g. GAE, AWS, CloudFoundry).

Alternatively, you can find an existing cloud framework such as [Amazon MapReduce](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=map%20reduce%20cloud&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~matei/talks/2009/parlab_bootcamp_clouds.ppt&ei=qOm3TsdArdyJArSC8JsO&usg=AFQjCNFSJIB8tdtOM4n488nxUUMOMZwJ6Q&sig2=jvddDLG1eXJiDEC5eITVkA) (link is to a ppt describing the tool) and fit your application into that framework.  This would probably be the fastest approach, especially if you don't have much experience with Servlets.